# Hibernate not able to create a table in the database.

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

When I am executing session.save(Object) Hibernate gives a many errors. I have posted this question on as many forums as possible

First error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'entity.listOfcases' doesn't exist`

Then I also see one more error:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
```

I have used "update" and "create" both in my hibernate mapping file but still the table does not get automatically created in the database.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Used both of them above.

Third error: `"org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator"`

I have checked all my getter setters and all the POJO classes. Everything is fine. When I create the tables manually everything works just great, its just that when I delete those tables and try to auto-create them, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `create` on its own?  If you manually made the schema did you try `create-drop` then switching to `create`?

Comment: But neither got executed. And the one that I created manually was in database named "test" and then I created a new DB named "entity" then made the changes in all the places necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Hibernate mapping file i.e. hibernate.cfg.xml make the following change:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
```

instead of whatever it says right now. I am assuming:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
```

This would definitely take care of all the errors if you say that you have checked rest of the code.

Comment: I will give this a try as well.

Comment: I cannot believe that this small change solved the issue. I have posted this on infinite number of forums but to no use. :-) 
Appreciate it.

Comment: Please post the code as well next time so that the reader can just copy/paste it in his/her IDE rahter than writing the rest of the part themselves.

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked when i updated the value from
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
to
 org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect